# Udacity Sunshine app with Android Studio - Error:(21) No resource identifier found for attribute 'actionProviderClass' in package '..'

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

I'm trying to add the share button on the action bar but the build fails because:

```
Error:(21) No resource identifier found for attribute 'actionProviderClass' in package '...'
```

My menu/detail.xml has:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item1.../>
<item2.../>

<item android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
    android:title="@string/action_share"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>

</menu>
```

(This is probably irrelevant but the instructions say to make android:showAsAction be app:showAsAction but that gets underlined and it says "Should use android:showAsAction when not using the appcompat library")

My thanks!

Comment: And what happens when you remove support. v7 from the actionProviderClass ?

Comment: try to change xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" to xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.exapmle.mypackage" where com.exapmle.mypackage will be your package name.

Comment: @PhilippeLePoint Happy to help.Please revert back to original question so it will be useful for others having same issue And always post new problem with new question.

Comment: @PhilippeLePoint Anyway this may help for your second problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118051/unable-to-cast-action-provider-to-share-action-provider

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto";
```

to

```
 xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.exapmle.mypackage";
```

where `com.exapmle.mypackage` will be your package name.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Also -

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

should instead be:

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

---

In DetailActivity.java, did you remember to add:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
```

Mine is below, it's exactly the same, although I did experience the same thing you're describing here. I had accidentally put:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto
```

instead of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:title="@string/action_share"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
</menu>
```